# Searches related to ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (103408, 1, 1)

Tags: python-3.x

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("vgg16_1.h5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=20, verbose=1, mode='auto')

## hist = model.fit(np.array([trainX]),epochs=100,callbacks=[checkpoint,early])

model.fit(np.array([trainX]), trainY,batch_size=16,epochs=100,shuffle=True,verbose=1,validation_data=(testX, testY),callbacks=[checkpoint,early])
i have tried this for numerical data not an image data

got the above result